# Grails GORM - Saves child before parent

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, parent-child, one-to-many

I have several classes that have a child parent relationship, however, when trying to save everything Grails GORM saves the child first, which ends up throwing the following error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found
```

Here's the basic code representation of my classes:

```
class Request
{
  // Mapping definitions
  static mapping = {
    table(name: 'FORMS_REQUEST')
    tablePerHierarchy(false)
    id(length: 20, precision: 20, scale: 0, generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'FORMS_REQUEST_SEQ'])       
  }

  // Properties
  Timestamp version
  Form form
  Date submittedTime
}
```

---

```
abstract class Form
{
  // Mapping definitions
  static mapping = {
    table(name: 'FORMS_FORM')
    tablePerHierarchy(false)
    id(length: 20, precision: 20, scale: 0, generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'FORMS_FORM_SEQ'])
  }

  // Relationship definitions
  static belongsTo = [request: Request]

  // Properties
  Timestamp version
}
```

---

```
class AccessForm extends Form
{
  // Mapping definitions
  static mapping = {
    table(name: 'FORMS_ACCESS_FORM')
    id(length: 20, precision: 20, scale: 0, generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_SEQ'])
  }

  // Relationship definitions
  static hasMany = [adGroups: AccessFormAD, printers: AccessFormPrinter]

  // Properties
  List adGroups
  List printers
}
```

---

```
class AccessFormAD
{
  // Mapping definitions
  static mapping = {
    table(name: 'FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD')
    id(length: 20, precision: 20, scale: 0, generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ'])
  }

  // Relationship definitions
  static belongsTo = [accessForm: AccessForm]

  // Properties
  Timestamp version
}
```

---

```
class AccessFormPrinter
{
  // Mapping definitions
  static mapping = {
    table(name: 'FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_PRINTER')
    id(length: 20, precision: 20, scale: 0, generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_PRINTER_SEQ'])
  }

  // Relationship definitions
  static belongsTo = [accessForm: AccessForm]

  // Properties
  Timestamp version
}
```

After creating all the classes with correct data, etc. and calling the following:

```
request.save(flush: true)
```

I get the error mentioned above.  The log shows the following SQL statements made by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select FORMS_REQUEST_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_FORM_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into FORMS_ACCESS_FORM_AD (version, checked, DN, type, access_form_id, ad_groups_idx, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Sep. 02 2014 @ 03:58:06 PM - class spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FK_954TU4QUPD4QE7H72XGVXSTKV) violated - parent key not found
```

It starts by saving the child objects before the parents, which would explain the error, however, I have no idea why (it seems silly that GORM is doing this) and I also don't know how to change GORM's (Hibernate's) behavior to save the parent first.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because your top level Request is using `Form form` instead of `static hasOne = [form:Form]`.

Comment: Interesting ... that fixed it.  Didn't think that would be required (since that is only required for one-to-one relationships when you want to change which table has the foreign key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the fact your `Request` domain class is using simple property assignment for the related `Form`.

So instead of `Form form` you need to use `static hasOne = [form:Form]` to define that relationship.

The reason being is that GORM determines the relationships by using such things as `hasOne` and `hasMany` and in turn can figure out what order things need to be inserted.